# Javascript Calculator, how do I clear the output when a new number is inputted?

Tags: javascript, calculator

I'm currently building a calculator project and I'm having a small issue. I'm able to get the output of the calculator (e.g., 2 x 2 = 4). However, if I input a new number afterwards, the number gets added to the string of the output. I would like to clear that output ONLY when a new number input is pressed (e.g., 2 x 2 = 4. I press 3, the currentDisplay will show as 43 instead of it just being "3"). Setting

```
currentNum = ""
```

after the output is created does fix this problem, however I wouldn't be able to use the output to chain operators if I did that (e.g., 5 x 2 = 10 +2 = 12)

Here is the full code:

```
let currentNum = "";
let prevNum = "";
let operator = "";
const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".num-btns")
const operatorButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".operator")
const equal = document.querySelector(".equal");
const dot = document.querySelector(".dot");
const clearBtn = document.querySelector(".clear");
const deleteBtn = document.querySelector(".delete");
const currentDisplay = document.querySelector(".current-number");
const prevDisplay = document.querySelector(".previous-number");


//add, subtract, multiply, and divide functions
function addFn(num1, num2) {
    return num1 + num2;
}

function subFn(num1, num2) {
    return num1 - num2;
}

function multiFn(num1, num2) {
    return num1 * num2;
}

function divFn(num1, num2) {
    return num1 / num2;
}


//operator function
function operate (a, b, c) {
    const num1 = parseFloat(a);
    const num2 = parseFloat(b);
    let output = 0;
    try {
  
      switch(c) {
        case '+':
          output = addFn(num1, num2);
          break;
  
        case 'x':
          output = multiFn(num1, num2);
          break;
  
        case '-':
          output = subFn(num1, num2);
          break;
  
       case '/':
          if (num2 === 0) {
            output = "ERROR"
          } else {
          output = divFn(num1, num2);
          }
          break;
      }
    }
    catch(e) {
      currentDisplay.textContent = ("There's an error: ", e)
    };
    currentDisplay.textContent = Math.round(output *100000) / 100000;
    currentNum = output;
}

equal.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (currentNum != "" && prevNum != "") {
  operate(prevNum, currentNum, operator);
  }
  prevNum = "";
});

//button inputs for numbers and operators
numberButtons.forEach(btn => {
    btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        handleNumber(e.target.textContent);
    });
});

function handleNumber(number) {
        currentNum += number;
        currentDisplay.textContent = currentNum;
}

operatorButtons.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    handleOperator(e.target.textContent);
  });
});

function handleOperator(op) {
  if (currentNum != "") {
    operator = op
    prevNum = currentNum
    prevDisplay.textContent = prevNum + " " + operator;
    currentNum = ""
    currentDisplay.textContent = "";
  }
}

function addDot() {
  if (!currentNum.includes(".")) {
    currentNum += ".";
    currentDisplay.textContent = currentNum;
  }
}

dot.addEventListener("click", () => {
  addDot();
})

//clear button
function reset() {
  currentDisplay.textContent = "";
  prevDisplay.textContent = "";
  currentNum = "";
  prevNum = "";
}

clearBtn.addEventListener("click", reset);

//delete button
function delNumber() {
  currentDisplay.textContent = currentDisplay.textContent
  .toString()
  .slice(0, -1);
  currentNum = currentDisplay.textContent;
}

deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", delNumber);
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="display">
        <div class="previous-number">
        </div>
        <div class="current-number"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="btns">
        <div>
            <button class="clear">AC</button>
            <button class="delete">DEL</button>
        </div>
        <div class="row1">
            <div class="num-btns1">
                <button class="num-btns">7</button>
                <button class="num-btns">8</button>
                <button class="num-btns">9</button>
                <button class="operator">/</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row2">
                <button class="num-btns">4</button>
                <button class="num-btns">5</button>
                <button class="num-btns">6</button>
                <button class="operator">x</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row3">
                <button class="num-btns">1</button>
                <button class="num-btns">2</button>
                <button class="num-btns">3</button>
                <button class="operator">-</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row4">
                <button class="dot">.</button>
                <button class="num-btns">0</button>
                <button class="equal">=</button>
                <button class="operator">+</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="./script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `=` button is clicked, set a variable to remember that the next number input should clear the previous number. (Then remove this catch once an operator button is clicked).

```js
let currentNum = "";
let prevNum = "";
let operator = "";
let clearOnNextNum = false;
const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".num-btns")
const operatorButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".operator")
const equal = document.querySelector(".equal");
const dot = document.querySelector(".dot");
const clearBtn = document.querySelector(".clear");
const deleteBtn = document.querySelector(".delete");
const currentDisplay = document.querySelector(".current-number");
const prevDisplay = document.querySelector(".previous-number");


//add, subtract, multiply, and divide functions
function addFn(num1, num2) {
    return num1 + num2;
}

function subFn(num1, num2) {
    return num1 - num2;
}

function multiFn(num1, num2) {
    return num1 * num2;
}

function divFn(num1, num2) {
    return num1 / num2;
}


//operator function
function operate (a, b, c) {
    const num1 = parseFloat(a);
    const num2 = parseFloat(b);
    let output = 0;
    try {
  
      switch(c) {
        case '+':
          output = addFn(num1, num2);
          break;
  
        case 'x':
          output = multiFn(num1, num2);
          break;
  
        case '-':
          output = subFn(num1, num2);
          break;
  
       case '/':
          if (num2 === 0) {
            output = "ERROR"
          } else {
          output = divFn(num1, num2);
          }
          break;
      }
    }
    catch(e) {
      currentDisplay.textContent = ("There's an error: ", e)
    };
    currentDisplay.textContent = Math.round(output *100000) / 100000;
    currentNum = output;
    clearOnNextNum = true;
}

equal.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (currentNum != "" && prevNum != "") {
  operate(prevNum, currentNum, operator);
  }
  prevNum = "";
});

//button inputs for numbers and operators
numberButtons.forEach(btn => {
    btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        handleNumber(e.target.textContent);
    });
});

function handleNumber(number) {
        if (clearOnNextNum) {
            clearOnNextNum = false;
            currentNum = "";
        }
        currentNum += number;
        currentDisplay.textContent = currentNum;
}

operatorButtons.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    handleOperator(e.target.textContent);
  });
});

function handleOperator(op) {
  clearOnNextNum = false;
  if (currentNum != "") {
    operator = op
    prevNum = currentNum
    prevDisplay.textContent = prevNum + " " + operator;
    currentNum = ""
    currentDisplay.textContent = "";
  }
}

function addDot() {
  clearOnNextNum = false;
  if (!currentNum.includes(".")) {
    currentNum += ".";
    currentDisplay.textContent = currentNum;
  }
}

dot.addEventListener("click", () => {
  addDot();
})

//clear button
function reset() {
  currentDisplay.textContent = "";
  prevDisplay.textContent = "";
  currentNum = "";
  prevNum = "";
}

clearBtn.addEventListener("click", reset);

//delete button
function delNumber() {
  currentDisplay.textContent = currentDisplay.textContent
  .toString()
  .slice(0, -1);
  currentNum = currentDisplay.textContent;
}

deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", delNumber);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="display">
        <div class="previous-number">
        </div>
        <div class="current-number"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="btns">
        <div>
            <button class="clear">AC</button>
            <button class="delete">DEL</button>
        </div>
        <div class="row1">
            <div class="num-btns1">
                <button class="num-btns">7</button>
                <button class="num-btns">8</button>
                <button class="num-btns">9</button>
                <button class="operator">/</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row2">
                <button class="num-btns">4</button>
                <button class="num-btns">5</button>
                <button class="num-btns">6</button>
                <button class="operator">x</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row3">
                <button class="num-btns">1</button>
                <button class="num-btns">2</button>
                <button class="num-btns">3</button>
                <button class="operator">-</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row4">
                <button class="dot">.</button>
                <button class="num-btns">0</button>
                <button class="equal">=</button>
                <button class="operator">+</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="./script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Declaring  a varible "calculated" initially set to false. and changed to true on evaluting the result ('=') .
    
  **scrpit.js**
  
    let input=document.getElementById('inputbox');
    let btns=document.querySelectorAll('button');
    
    let str="";
    let arr=Array.from(btns);
    var calculated=false;
    
    arr.forEach((b) =>{
        b.addEventListener('click', (e) =>{
            if(e.target.innerHTML == '=') {
                    str=eval(str).toFixed(1);
                    input.value=str;
                    calculated=true;
            }
            else if(e.target.innerHTML == 'C'){
                str= '';
                input.value=str;
            }
            else if(e.target.innerHTML == 'DEL')
            {
                str=str.slice(0,-1);
                input.value=str;
            }
            else if(e.target.innerHTML == '+/-'){
                str=e.target.innerHTML;
                if(str<0){
                    str=str* -1;
                    input.value=str;
                }
                else if(str >0){
                    str=Math.abs(str);
                    input.value=str;
    
                }
                
            }
            else{
                if(calculated == true){
                    str='';
                    input.value=str;
                    calculated=false;
                }
                str+=e.target.innerHTML;
                input.value=str;
            }
        })
    })


**index.html**
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Simple Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Calculator</h1>
    <div class="container">
            <input type="text" class="item1" id="inputbox" value="0"></input>
            <button class="items btn" >7</button>
            <button class="items btn">8</button>
            <button class="items btn">9</button>
            <button class="items btn operator">%</button>
            <button class="del btn operator">DEL</button>

            <button class="items btn">4</button>
            <button class="items btn">5</button>
            <button class="items btn">6</button>
            <button class="items btn operator">*</button>
            <button class="items btn operator">/</button>

            <button class="items btn">1</button>
            <button class="items btn">2</button>
            <button class="items btn">3</button>
            <button class="items btn operator">-</button>
            <button class="equals btn">=</button>

            <button class="items btn" id="clear">C</button>
            <button class="items btn">0</button>
            <button class="items btn operator">.</button>
            <button class="items btn operator">+</button>
            <script src="./script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    </div>

</body>
</html>

**style.css**
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px 15px 60px 15px;
    font-weight: bolder;

}
.container{
    border: 5px solid black;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns : repeat(5,1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(5,1fr);
    row-gap: 12px;
    column-gap: 12px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 30px;
    background-color: rgb(173, 239, 239);
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.item1{
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 6;
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 15px;
    margin:2px;
    text-align:right;
    font-weight: bolder;
    background-color: rgb(214, 238, 238);
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.item1:hover{
    background-color: white;
}
.equals{
    grid-column: 5;
    grid-row: 4/span 2;
    border: 2px solid black;
    justify-self: center;
    padding: 50px 15px;
    margin: 5px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    background-color:darkblue;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.equals:hover{
    background-color: white;
    color: blue;
}
.del {
    border: 2px solid black;
    justify-self: center;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 5px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    background-color: rgb(214, 238, 238);
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.items{
    display: grid;
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 5px;
    width:50px;
    height: 60px;
    font-weight:bolder;
    align-self: center;
    background-color: rgb(214, 238, 238);
    color:darkblue;
    border-radius: 10px;
    
}
#clear{
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}
#clear:hover{
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    color: brown;
}
#operator{
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(163, 160, 160);
}
#operator:hover{
    background-color:rgb(223, 223, 165);
    color:red;
}
.items:hover,.del:hover{
    background-color:rgb(223, 223, 165);
    color:white;

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).